# There is a way to index datatable/CSV to Elasticsearch

Tags: jquery, asp.net, elasticsearch, kibana

I am using .NET CORE 2.

I have searched for a long time for a way to to upload a CSV or Datatable through .NET (without using Logstash).

(Logstash require to configure an custom conf file for each csv).

TNX !

Comment: Google found this: https://bytefish.de/blog/elasticsearch_net/

Comment: @Val Tnx , but i am searching for an generic way to upload csv's. [Every CSV has a different columns number ]